# How can i write an adaptive method to use my library in the right way?

Tags: c#, events, dining-philosopher

I have a library and theres one problem with the logic in my program. If you can help me - i will say you : "Thank you" . really big thanks.
Code :

```
 public class Report
{

    /// <summary>
    /// An empty constructor, just instantiates the object.
    /// </summary>
    public Report()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A method that receives a message from another object,
    /// and prints it out to the Console.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be printed.</param>
    public void ReceiveMessage(String message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

private Report reportObject;
```

public void EnterThinkingState()
        {

```
        Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(1000) + 1);
        Status = "thinking";
        reportObject.ReceiveMessage(Name + " is " + Status);
        Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(1000) + 1);
    }
```

the Question is : My classes - are a library. How can i create an adaptive method (Receive) that a user could use to output information wherever he wants(logger,console,file e.t.c).
should i use virtual methods? Or create an interface? Or how  can i bind it with events?I know how to use events if we talk about typical situation.
Thank you for the help.
And, again, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Dependency Injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different approach to achieve this.
The below code show how to define an interface and use it :

```
 public interface IReceiverBase
 {
     void ReceiveMessage(string message);
 }

 public class Report
 {
     private readonly IReceiverBase _iReceiverBase;

     public Report(IReceiverBase iReceiverBase)
     {
         _iReceiverBase = iReceiverBase;
     }

     public void DoSomething()
     {
         // Do something here
         _iReceiverBase.ReceiveMessage("Something done ...");
     }
 }

 public class ConsoleMessageReceiver : IReceiverBase
 {
     public void ReceiveMessage(string message)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(message);
     }
 }

 public class DebugMessageReceiver : IReceiverBase
 {
     public void ReceiveMessage(string message)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine(message);
     }
 }

 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var repConsole = new Report(new ConsoleMessageReceiver());
         repConsole.DoSomething();

         var repDebug = new Report(new DebugMessageReceiver());
         repDebug.DoSomething();

         Console.Read();
     }
 }
```

Comment: No need to say thanks for answers. if the answer is useful and solve the problem just mark it as answer. Good Luck.

Comment: press the green tick , if this is the right solution, so everyone could benefit as well @TetsuaKeito